# Django using same APIView for both logged in and non logged in users

Tags: django, authentication, public

How can we use the same Django rest APIView for both logged in and logged out (Public) users.
If the authentication token is passed, the view should be able to give the request.user and if the authentication token is not passed, the request.user can be anonymous. Please let me know if this is possible or not?

I tried to remove

authentication_classes = []
permission_classes = []

from the view, but by default the authentication is applied for all the users.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using **`authentication_classes = [] permission_classes = []`** you can do like this...

```
class ProductAPI(APIView):

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            # for logged in user
        else:
            # for logged out user
```